# How to count the amount of times an index has been changed in a list

Tags: python, list

So basically, I'm creating a function that takes a list and 2 values. The function replaces all occurrences of the first value with the second, The function has to then return the number of replacements that were completed.

I've managed to make the code work, but when it prints the number of replacements that were completed, it says 1, when there were in fact 2 replacements completed. It's as if it only checks for the first index and then stops. I don't where I went wrong.

```
def functionTwo(numberList, checkNum, checkNumTwo):
    try:
        while True:
            num = numberList.index(checkNum)
            numberList[num] = checkNumTwo
            amount = numberList.count(checkNumTwo)
            return amount
    except ValueError:
        pass

numberList = [4,8,22,43,42,12,1,10,1,10,32,28,8,42,13]
result = functionTwo(numberList, 1, 3)
print(result)
```

Comment: `return amount` should not be in the loop, you return after the first replacement.

Comment: @Barmar if i don't put it in the loop, python either says invalid syntax or it just prints 'None' - where would i put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `index` repeatedly is an overly complex way to do it, it searches the entire list over and over, which is O(n<sup>2</sup>). Just iterate over the list once and replace the elements as you go, incrementing a counter.

```
def functionTwo(numberList, checkNum, checkNumTwo):
    counter = 0
    for i, val in enumerate(numberList):
        if val == checkNum:
            numberList[i] = checkNumTwo
            counter += 1
    return counter
```

However, to fix your code, just move `return amount` into the `except ValueError:` block. Your code was returning after the first replacement, so of course it returned only 1.

```
def functionTwo(numberList, checkNum, checkNumTwo):
    try:
        while True:
            num = numberList.index(checkNum)
            numberList[num] = checkNumTwo
    except ValueError:
        return numberList.count(checkNumTwo)
```

Note that using `count()` assumes that the list didn't contain any occurrences of `checkNumTwo` initially, because they'll be counted.